# how to write a lambda function that update dynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have my lambda function as follow:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-2'});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const phone=event.phoneNumber;
     const amount=event.amountChange;
    const updateParams = {
    TableName: "mytable",
    Key: {
        phoneNumber: 
            phone
        
    },
    UpdateExpression: "SET #a = #a + :incre",
     ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#a': 'balance.amount',
  },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":incre": 
            amount
        
    },
};
  await dynamodb.updateItem(updateParams).promise();

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Balance updated successfully')
  };
};
```

and test event

```
{
  "phoneNumber": "+XXXXXXXXXX",
  "amountChange": 100
}
```

the error i got while testing

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "Unrecognized operation \"undefined\"",
  "trace": [
    "Error: Unrecognized operation \"undefined\"",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:39:19)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:74:25)"
  ]
}
```

I want to update the value which in dynamoDB attribute balance.amount. But I am getting the above error. Which part of code did I done wrong? phoneNumber is my primary key in DDB.

Comment: are you event.phoneNumber is defined because events are inside event.Records[0]. 
it is better to perform `console.log(event)` to understand the structure of event lambda is receiving and then start extracting required values.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the latest node runtime for Lambda then you need to use JavaScript SDK V3 as that is the SDK built for that runtime. You are using SDK V2 here.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-18-x-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/